# how to get torch.Size([1, 3, 16, 112, 112]) instead of torch.Size([1, 3, 16, 64, 64]) after ConvTranspose3d

Tags: pytorch, convolution

I have a `torch.Size([1, 64, 8, 32, 32])` which I want after my transpose 3d convolution to become `torch.Size([1, 3, 16, 112, 112])`.

Using this: `nn.ConvTranspose3d(64, 3, kernel_size=4, stride=2, bias=False, padding=(1, 1, 1))` I get correct the output channels and the number of frames, but not the frame sizes:`torch.Size([1, 3, 16, 64, 64])`

What should I change in order to the right torch.Size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use different strides and paddings for different dims.

`ConvTranspose3d(64, 3, kernel_size=4, stride=(2, 4, 4), bias=False, padding=(1, 8, 8))`

Comment: Thanks for your response! Would it be possible to have the same result by using different kernel size for these two dimensions ? something like: ```ConvTranspose3d(64, 3, kernel_size=(4,X,X), stride=(2, 4, 4), bias=False, padding=(1, 1, 1))``` Does it make any sense actually to do so?

Comment: yeah, you can use different kernel sizes for different dims as well.